# Bugreport in Android says wm_destroy_activity...low-mem

Tags: android, low-memory

it might be a dumb question but I could not find an answer to my question:

In my bugreport, created via adb, I can see the following entry:

```
11-20 16:24:34.720  1000  1772 16182 I wm_destroy_activity: [0,139984888,28775,xxx.runningtracker/.MapsActivity,low-mem]
```

This entry happens, I assume, that I am fetching my location in a ForegroundService every second, every meter and then displaying the route on Google maps.
Maybe, the ArrayList is filling up but it is strange that it has only 1300 entries.
In my opinion not that much (but I might be wrong!).
Before I made some changes and these changes did not affect the ArrayList I was able to save more than 100.000 points and Android never forced to stop it.

Am I right that this information above tells me that I am running out of memory (low-mem)?

Thanks in advance!